# Heroku python console app module ImportError

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I've encountered an issue while trying to access PostgreSQL from heroku python console (first attempt).

First up, I launch python using `$ heroku run python`

Then I try to load up the db module with `>>> from app import db`, this action returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named app
```

I have one web dyno running python which has `app = Flask(__name__)`, apart from that, I don't know what other details should I provide in order to shed more light into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with the terminal, it became clear, that there really is no way for it to know what variables do I have in my `main.py`, so what I did then was load the main parts of the app through the terminal like so:

```
>>> import os
>>> from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
>>> from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

>>> # create the application
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> app.config.from_object(__name__)
>>> app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'some-url.com')
>>> db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And from then on I was able to access the `db` object as intended.

EDIT - the issue completely resolved below.

So the reason I was having an error while trying to import my apps code into the python shell was two fold:

1. The *.py that was the target of my import was not at the root directory, I was telling the shell to look in the **wrong place**.
2. Since the *.py I was importing was not named app.py (and I was asking to `from app import db`), I was also telling the shell to look for the **wrong file**.

The way to solve this issue was to append the path of my *.py file to the sys.path and instead of `from app import db`, us `from my_filename_without_the_extenssion import db`. For a summary, the shell received these instructions:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('path/to/my/file')
>>> from my_filename_without_the_extenssion import db
>>> # to test if everythings ok
>>> db
```